# Why do people make lame edits to my post?

Tags: discussion

Somebody just edited my post! They removed the last line in the post, that was just my name. This is a 3 years old post, that was answered very competently by @john-powell, 3 years ago.

What is the point in editing it? Is it a way of collecting reputation points or medals, or is someone just really keen on people not signing their posts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They get 2 points for the accepted edit - community standards say we don't add signatures, thanks or other "unnecessary" fluff to our questions or answers.

There's no harm in tidying up questions or answers when you happen across them, personally I have better things to do with my time than to go hunting, though I will usually fix typos in titles (as people use those for searching etc) when I see them.